# The named parameter 'bloc' isn't defined - bloc provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I've read the flutter-bloc documentation and I really have no idea what to do anymore. Someone to help?

[error bloc provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDqh.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't import the Bloc package into this file.

Comment: import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart'; yes it is imported :/

Comment: try this `import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';`

Comment: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

Comment: try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` commands in the terminal

Comment: I tried and I'm still the same :/

Comment: What package do you have ? bloc, flutter_bloc or what hehe

Comment: only import 'package:bloc_pattern/bloc_pattern.dart';

Comment: The only way I think is that if you have already added the package to pubspec.yaml, run `flutter pub get` to re-attach it to your project.

Comment: I already realized it at this point

Answer (score 0):

Try `create:` instead of `bloc:`

```
BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
      create: (context) => UserBloc(),
      child: Container(),
    );
```